# Cpp main method const declaration

Tags: c++, constants, program-entry-point

Why can't we declare main method as const in CPP??

```
int main() const 
{
   //Some code
}
```

Someone can please tell me why?

Comment: What functionality you want to acheive by declaring it const?

Comment: What error are you getting? If it's during compilation or linkage, then it probably answers your question.

Comment: I am just digging.... Not trying to achieve any functionality

Comment: Well, there's your answer. It doesn't achieve any functionality, hence it would just be pointless and confusing. So it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't we declare main method as const in CPP??

`const` qualifiers can be used only to declare member functions of classes. It is not an option for non-member functions, which `main` is one.

Comment: Yeah but why const is not available for non member function?

Comment: @MohanPatil, A const-member function implies that you cannot change the non-mutable member variables of the object on which it is called. There is no such thing for a non-member function. Which object will be subject to that constraint when a function is a non-member function?

Comment: @R Sahu - as OS is calling main then there will be no object... Therefore the constraint of const function declaration cannot be applied  here.... That's why main can not be declared const... Right?

Comment: @MohanPatil, you are welcolme. Glad I was able to help.